# plot phase portrait in matlab

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I have solved the first part of this question. can any one please help to plot this using ODE in matlab. at least for one condition.

Comment: I must sadly admit that [this](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~efendiev/math442_spring04/matlabode.pdf) is the best I've found around...there's not plenty of examples of "just" a linear system. Check pages 3 and 9 in particular, hope it can help

Comment: I got the answer.Thank you for the reference

Comment: @MattAllegro I got the answer

Answer (score 1):

0<λ1 <λ2

[image]

λ1 <λ2<0

[image]

λ1<0 <λ2

[image]

λ1,λ2 = a±ib

a>0

[image]

λ1,λ2 = a±ib

a<0

[image]

λ1,λ2 = a±ib

a=0

[image]